# ImportError: No module named googlemaps

Tags: macos, python-2.7, google-maps, pip, macports

I've installed this [package](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) via pip27 on macports. My OS is OSX El Capitan 10.11.6. My python install is 2.7.10.

I'm trying to run an example script that imports googlemaps module, but I keep getting that ImportError. I have a feeling that it's how pip installed it and the reason why python can't find it, but I'm relatively new to pip so I don't know where to start investigating.

I also tried googling for a fix but no dice. Any idea what's happening here?

Here's my code:

```
import googlemaps # can't import
import argparse
from datetime import datetime

# collect args for lat, long, # of addresses, radius of search
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Randomize addresses on Google Maps')
parser.add_argument('-lt', '--latitude')
parser.add_argument('-lng', '--longitude')
parser.add_argument('-n', '--count')
parser.add_argument('-r', '--radius')
args = parser.parse_args()

print('Results: ', vars(args))
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "randomize_addresses.py", line 1, in <module>
    import googlemaps
ImportError: No module named googlemaps
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix. I uninstalled googlemaps via pip and then reinstalled using easy_install. Apparently OSX doesn't like pip.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you used pre-installed python since you mentioned version 2.7.10 (default version shipped with macOS) which is located at `/usr/bin/`.

MacPorts installs binaries and libraries under `/opt/local`. Try to install python via MacPorts and run the program again. Python and pip should both be linked so that packages installed via pip is available to python.

In this case packages installed using pip27 would be available to python27 installed via MacPorts and not `/usr/bin/python`.

Another way would be to download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and install it against `/usr/bin/python` ([pip installation guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)).

Note: Make sure you are using python installed via MacPorts. To check this run `which python`, it should show something like `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`